# Converting private or protected method to public

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

It's possible to call private methods using `send` but is there a way to somehow monkey-patch the class to call it in a regular way?

Comment: It's not "ranting about how private methods are private for a reason". These language features are there for a reason, and are not designed to be easily circumvented. You can, as you already pointed out, circumvent it with `.send()`. You could, perhaps, also monkey patch it, why don't you try it? But ... why? It is a perfectly sane and reasonable question designed to help you accomplish your goal, as it looks like you're using the wrong tool to fix this problem...

Comment: The method in question is `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_array`

Comment: Why do you want to call that method? What are you trying to accomplish? What is the problem that needs fixing with that tool?

Comment: Obviously, I need to issue a complex query that can only be expressed as SQL and I need to sanitize user input.

Comment: What else could be the answer? I'm using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` to issue a query a need to sanitize the string it accepts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Module#public` does the trick.

```
class Foo
  private
  def hello
    "hello"
  end
end

class Foo
  public :hello
end
```

Comment: Excellent approach

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to convert private method to public. Still you could do this like this.

Consider your original class and method as below

```
class A
  private
  def a
    p "hello"
  end
end
```

You could convert this method `a` to public as below

```
class A
  alias_method :original_a, :a
  def a
    original_a
  end
end
```

The idea is we make an aliased copy of original method and then call this original private method from a public method with the same name.